# Which MPLAB-X version supports Pickit 2?

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab, pickit, mplabx

I got myself a Microchip Pickit-2 Programmer from a local store. I installed MPLAB release v2.26 from Microchip's website.

However, in this version of MPLAB, it is not detecting my Pickit-2. Hovering over the "Tools" field of MPLAB window indeed reveals that Pickit-2 is not supported, as shown in the attached screen-shot.

I want to ask which version of MPLAB supports Pickit 2? Or, does MPLAB even support it? Should I go for some other software?

FYI, I am running this on Linux.

[image: MPLAB v2.26 on Linux]

Comment: The [latest MPLAB X](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/) is 3.20, not 2.26. Can you confirm what you're asking? The support for PICKit 2 *is* deprecated but that's all described in the various release notes.

Comment: Oh, thanks @RogerRowland for correcting. I am sorry. Yes, the latest release is indeed v3.20. I had an old binary lying around in my computer of v2.26. So, my question is exactly this: I know that support for Pickit 2 is deprecated, but in which MPLAB-X version did this happen? Is their an older MPLAB-X version that supports Pickit-2?

Comment: Your best bet is to just try it out first. Often they say its not supported, but it may still work. That said, your problem may not only be mplab. Very probably your microcontroller will also not support pickit2, if it is a current one.

Comment: That dsPIC30F1010 device [is not supported on PICKit 2](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/dts.aspx?device=DSPIC30F1010&filter=) anyway it seems.

Comment: PS: don't nail me on that one, but is pickit2 not deprechated since the introduction of mplabX? maybe try an old mplab8 version?

Comment: @jwsc Yes. Maybe I will have to go for MPLAB 8. But I think it's Windows only, right?

Comment: @RogerRowland: Thanks for pointing out the support issue for dsPIC30F1010. But I think it will work. Thing is, Microchip has removed Pickit-2 from all the chips' support pages. Even older chips' pages don't show Pickit-2 as supported. BTW, I have a dsPIC2010 and the local store guy said that it is supported.

Comment: You are right. Maybe try one of the first mplabx? Microchip has a mplabX archive here: http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/ You may find a release note with supported debug devices in the archives, too

Comment: Just watched [EEVBlog #841](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfmLu6XzBtw) about the difficulty in getting a PK3 working with anything. A little long-winded, but some good tidbits in there. Just get an ICD3 - that works with almost everything.

Comment: @rdtsc: Haha... Yep, EEVBlog does good bashing :) Anyways, ICD3 is gonna be too costly for me. I'm just trying to get my PK2 to work on Linux.

Comment: I would take the PICkit 2 back and get at least a PICkit 3.  It is fully supported, since as you mentioned, ICD 3 is a lot more expensive.  There are also a lot of PICkit 3 clones out there.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is download the standalone PICKIT2 programming software and use that to manually load the hex file MPLAB generates and program your PIC. That's what I do if I'm using the PICKIT2 with MPLAB-X v3.15.

I haven't tried with Linux though. However, it seems there is a command line tool for Linux here: http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=pg164120

Look for the PK2CMD.

A simple guide: http://curuxa.org/en/Program_PICs_with_a_PICkit2_using_the_command_line_on_Linux

I'm curious as to how that goes. On my Linux computer, I use PICKIT3, but it would still be nice to know that the PICKIT2 can be used.

Comment: Thanks for all the info @Tahmid. I'll look into it and revert back.

Answer (score 2):

I have the (PICKit 2 compatible) iCP01, and I just installed MPLAB X 4.05 on Mac OS. I can't get the IPE to work, same as the screenshot shows.

However, by creating a project in the IDE, I can select PICkit 2 as my hardware tool, and successfully program the chip.

So, it appears that it is only unsupported in the IPE.

Answer (score 1):

The device support list for PICkit2 at http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PICkit%202%20Readme%20v2-61-00%20(a).txt does list your dsPIC30F1010 - so you should be able to find an MPLAB version which works.
That file is dated 24 March 2009, so if you can find something from way back then .....

Comment: Thanks @brhans for the confirmation that my device will work. But that still doesn't answer my question. I want to know is their any software for Pickit2 which works on Linux?

Comment: @shivams have you tried out your current mplabx version already? pickit2 is listed in the configuration section, so it should be possible to use it, even if it says that it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I use PICKit2 for programming in MPLABX 5.10. The "hold in reset doesn't seem to work properly. It does program my chip (16F887). I added the line:

> ATTR{idVendor}=="04d8", ATTR{idProduct}=="0033", MODE="666", RUN+="%E{hotplugscript} add"

to  `z010_mchp_tools.rules` file in /etc/udev/rules.d
A reboot will be required, or use the following lines in console window:

> service udev restart
> sudo udevadm control --reload-rules